# if add_vertex in BGL checks for the existence of the vertex

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

In BGL, `add_edge` checks if the edge already exists. Is there the same mechanism for `add_vertex`? 
For example, if we have a vertex with some `bundled_properties`, and then we add it to the graph, and then connect an edge to it, would be this vertex **duplicated** if there was a similar vertex?

Comment: how do you define "similar vertex". If you add a vertex, you get a new vertex by definition. If you want to keep indices by some other key, they're outside your graph.

Comment: You might be interested in the labeled graph adaptor, though https://stackoverflow.com/q/43114533/85371

Comment: When two vertices have similar properties (internal, or bundled) they are the same vertex, and `add_vertex` instead of adding it with new index shouldn't just return the index to an existing one? I am aware of `labeled_graph`, and I've already upvoted that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When two vertices have similar properties (internal, or bundled) they are the same vertex, and add_vertex instead of adding it with new index shouldn't just return the index to an existing one? – [Bruce 11 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713682/if-add-vertex-in-bgl-checks-for-the-existence-of-the-vertex?noredirect=1#comment78427001_45713682)

If you have two vertices with "similar properties", *you* decide whether you want to add another vertex with those properties or not.

> if we have a vertex with some bundled_properties, and then we add it to the graph, and then connect an edge to it, would be this vertex duplicated if there was a similar vertex?

You add edges by referring to `vertex_descriptor`s. There is no way to "connect an edge to vertex properties". So, `add_edge` cannot accidentally create a new vertex using some property.

> **Note**: There might be confusion because using `vectorS`² for vertex container selector lets you add edges by referring to potentially non-existing vertex descriptors. Really, that doesn't "add vertices" as much as it "extends the valid domain for vertex ids/descriptors". E.g.:
>
> ```
> adjacency_list<> g;
> add_edge(10, 11, g);
> ```
>
> doesn't really add 12 vertices. It extends the vertex id domain to encompass the value `11`. [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/964eaf54269c0070)

## Let's look at `add_vertex`:

The call is `add_vertex` and it adds a vertex. In fact, you don't usually insert properties for them, that's merely a convenience.

There is no fundamental difference between:

```
vertex_descriptor v = add_vertex(g);

g[v] = vertexProperties;
```

And

```
vertex_descriptor v = add_vertex(vertexProperties, g);
```

In both cases you will *always* get a new, unique, vertex descriptor, and have its properties set to a specific value.

### Why the difference with `add_edge` then?

Is `add_edge` really different? Like with `add_vertex` there is no difference between:

```
vertex_descriptor from {/*...*/}, to {/*...*/};
edge_descriptor e = add_edge(from, to, g).first;

g[e] = edgeProperties;
```

And

```
edge_descriptor e = add_edge(from, to, edgeProperties, g).first;
```

You will note that both (possibly) add an edge, returning its descriptor, and both set the properties to specific values.

> The important point here is that `adjacency_list` does ***not*** know or care about the properties. They add information for you, or useful for certain algorithms, but they are *not* relevant to the graph concept modeled by `adjacency_list`.

### Why does `add_edge` *conditionally* add?

That's because the `adjacency_list` uses strategies that imply invariants that need to be checked:

- if your edge-container selection happens to be e.g. `setS`, its insertion method may or may not insert a new edge; `adjacency_lists<>` just forwards the behaviour¹ to `add_edge`
- if your `adjacency_list` uses `undirected` or `bidirectional` as well, this puts extra contraints on edges (e.g. preventing addition of `(a->b)` as well as `(b->a)` in a bidirectional graph that uses `setS` as the edge container selector).

Summarizing:

> - `add_vertex` does ***not*** take any identifying information, hence it doesn't need to check for constraints (in fact, it cannot).
> - `add_edge` *does* take identifying information (the endpoint vertices) and it can check these against the constraints that arise from the strategies that you chose when instantiating the `adjacency_list`.

---

¹ e.g. to elegantly avoid doubled edges

² or possibly other Random Access vertex container selectors, that have integral vertex descriptors that act as *implicit* vertex id